# Get parent name of a user GridView Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to get the parent username of a user

The 'parent.username' works this way:

But I need url the user profile, and I have it like this

```
[

'attribute' => 'parent_id',
 'value' => function(User $model) {
 return Html::a(Html::encode($model->parent_id ? $model->parent_id : " "), ['view', 'id' => $model->parent_id]);
 },
 'format' => 'raw',

]
```

It is possible to get the username?

Thank you

Comment: You need to show the parent_id function to us. I presume (based on the code above) the User class has a function getParent_Id()

Comment: Yes, I have getParent and getChildren function.

 public function getParent(): ActiveQuery
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, ['id' => 'parent_id']);
    }

    public function getChildren(): ActiveQuery
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, ['parent_id' => 'id']);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the User class:

```
public function getParent(){
   return $this->hasOne(User::class,['id'=>'parent_id']);
}
```

In the gridView:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'parent.id', // or parent.first_name (whatever is relevant to you)
    'value' => function($model) {
       if(isset($model->parent->id)) // or parent->first_name (whatever is relevant to you)
         return Html::a(Html::encode($model->parent->id), 
             ['view', 'id' => $model->parent->id]);
      return "not found";
     },
    'format' => 'html',
]
```

Comment: Please mark your question as answered. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

In the User class:

```
public function getParent(){
   return $this->hasOne(User::class,['id'=>'parent_id']);
}
```

In the gridView:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'parent_id',
    'label' => 'User Name',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
          $name = Html::a($dataProvider->parent->username,['view','id'=>$dataProvider->parent_id]);
     return $name;
    },
],
```

Comment: For same reason,  return this error Trying to get property of non-object